# nodeJS - ioredis NPM Module - Having problem's with subscriber events

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, redis, ioredis

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');

const sub = new Redis();
const pub = new Redis();

sub.on('subscribe', (channel, count) => {
    console.log("Subbed to channel: " + channel);
})

sub.on('message', (channel, message) => {
    console.log("Message recieved: " + message);
})

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Attempting");
    sub.subscribe("hey");
    pub.publish("hey", "msg");
}, 2000);
```

**This is the code I've been using to test, this produces the following console output:**

```
Attempting

Message recieved: msg
```

**Expected output:**

```
Attempting

Subbed to channel: hey

Message recieved: msg
```

The sub.on('subscribe') event doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: Where did you find the `sibscribe` event? I can't find it from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
sub.subscribe(channel, (error, count) => {
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
    console.log(`Subscribed to ${count} channel. Listening for updates on the ${channel} channel.`);
});
```